# Can I view the manifest version of my spotify app in the Spotify player?

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to determine if an update to my Spotify application has gone live after submission.

Is there a way to inspect this value via the Spotify player? If not, how can I user the API to programmatically access this information so it can be displayed through my app?

Answer (score 1):

In the bundle manager (Developer -> Show Bundle Manager) you can see what apps are available and see it's version number. There's also a "manifest" option but at least in my version of Spotify it shows nothing. However I guess seeing the version number is enough for you.

Comment: thank you; the newest version of the Spotify player (just went live today) now puts this information right at the top of the "Develop" menu.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of the Spotify player (just went live today) now puts this information right at the top of the "Develop" menu.